# Writing to a file and simultaneously reading it to create a race condition in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs, node-streams

I'm trying to write to a file and simultaneously read it. I am able to write data to the file but the unable to read from it. No error is thrown when I do this and only the **End** event is being called on the read file stream.

I recently read that we cannot have race conditions in JS as it is single-threaded and race conditions are only created due to bad designs in a program. So, I tried to fiddle around and tried to create a race condition. I was expecting node to throw some error but came across this unexpected output.

```
const readFile = fs.createReadStream('./1GB.bin');
const writeFile = fs.createWriteStream('./test.bin');
const read = fs.createReadStream('./test.bin');

readFile.pipe(writeFile);

try {
    read.on('data', data => {
        console.log("data!", data.length);
    })

    read.on('end', _ => {
        console.log("END!");
    })

    read.on('error', err => console.log("Phatt gaya!"))
}
catch (err) {
    console.log("CAN't read 2nd file!");
}
```

**Expected Result**: Throw an error on trying to read the file

**Actual Result**: No error is thrown and only the **End** event is triggered

Does anyone have any idea on why is it functioning like this?

Link to the race condition article in case someone is interested:
[https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/06/17/no-there-are-no-race-conditions-in-javascript/]

Answer (score -1):

The above behavior is happening because writeStream erases the content of the file and then read stream gets the file as empty which in turn triggers the **End** event on the read stream.

Comment: but what's the solution? :)